# Unable to click on links cyclically from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to click on few links cyclically from a webpage. First off the scraper is supposed to click on the search button (without changing anything in the search fields) on the landing page to populate results.

STEP ONE:

When the results show up, the scraper should click on each of the links which I've tried to show in the first image.
After clicking on any link there is a box holding more information pop up.

STEP TWO:

In the pop up box there are few tabs hiding few more information which get revealed upon click (the new tabs are visible in image 3).

FINALLY:

However, the scraper is meant to keep on doing the same until all the links are exhausted.

What I have tried with can almost get all things done. It does all the above steps once (for the first link) but for the second link the scraper gets stuck in the last line of my script  throwing `timeout exception` error. Any help to make it a go will be highly appreciated.

Website address: [site link](https://www.mspa-ea.org/search-mspa-companies.html)

This is what I have tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver ; import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.mspa-ea.org/search-mspa-companies.html")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "element-button"))).click() #clicking on search button
for post in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".company a"))):
    post.click() #clicking on each links shown in image one
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".memberDetail .informationContainer ul li"))):
            elem.click() #clicking on tabs cyclically
            time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".memberDetail .closeDetail"))).click()
    #close the pop up box.
    #timeout exception throws here when it cycles for the second time
```

However, after doing all this for a single link when it goes for another link to repeat the action, it opens up the pop up box and instead of clicking on the tabs it directly hits the last line and throws `timeout exception`. Moreover, I could not get rid of hardcoded delays defined within my scraper.

Images are as follows (one, two and three are in order):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLvVY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK2R4.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7pG5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, rather than getting the exception at the call to `click`, I get the exception at the following line:

```
for elem in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".memberDetail .informationContainer ul li"))):
```

This line is not doing what you want it to be doing - that selector is going to return **all** of the `<li>` tab elements on the page (about 5000 of them), not just the ones in contained within the post that you have opened.

Since most of these `<li>` elements are not visible (since the popups containing them are closed), your call to `visibility_of_all_elements_located` is timing out.

You need to replace the above line of code with one which returns only the `<li>` tab elements which are descendants of the `post` WebElement which is currently open.

Comment: That problem can be fixed by using `presence` in place of `visibility` as in `for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".memberDetail .informationContainer ul li")))`. However, when clicking on those tabs are done then the browser can't close the pop up box to go for the next link.